# Use javascript prompts in google script web app

Tags: javascript, web-applications, google-apps-script

Good day. I'm trying to use some JavaScript methods listed below to make pop-up at the user end in browser, but being an amateur developer, I dont know how to make google script recognize them, and browser.msgBox will work only in docs, and not in browser.

```
window.alert()
window.confirm()
window.prompt()
```

Thanks a lot in advance for any quick help.